# How to Clearly Express Long List of Conditions?

Tags: javascript, c#

Consider the following if statement for an action game,

```
if (state.isPrimaryJumping && state.timeUntilCanJump == 0 && state.isStartPrimaryJumping && state.jumpIsLoaded && state.primaryJumpsSinceTouchedGround < moveStats.maxJumps) {
  // do awesome jumping stuff
}
```

In this case, each one of the six conditions are distinct and none can be removed. However, the statement wraps past the end of the page and is hard to understand.

What is the clearest way to express a long list of important conditions?

Thanks

Comment: wrap it in a method with a name that clearly expresses what the condition means?

Comment: @Eser I think the code being poorly formatted is largely the point of this question...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes, I answered it by formatting the question :)

Comment: @IanMcLaird said it, but you can see an example at https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-explaining-variable

Comment: @Fuhrmanator There is also an example below.

Comment: Many IDEs support the named refactoring however @stuartl

Answer (score 3):

When getting into long if statements like this, it is common to separate each condition by a newline:

```
if (state.isPrimaryJumping && 
    state.timeUntilCanJump == 0 && 
    state.isStartPrimaryJumping && 
    state.jumpIsLoaded && 
    state.primaryJumpsSinceTouchedGround < moveStats.maxJumps) 
{
  // do awesome jumping stuff
}
```

I prefer to put the && at the end of the line, starting the next line with a conditional instead of an operator, but either will work. Stuff like that is typically included in your organizations style guide as well.

Comment: I find the problem with this is that the second statement onward looks confusingly like its part of the `{}` block

Answer (score 3):

To make it more readable, I would put your statements into a method with a descriptive name that returns a `bool`. Something like this:

```
if (CanDoAwesomeJumpingStuff()) 
{
  // do awesome jumping stuff
}

private bool CanDoAwesomeJumpingStuff()
{
    return state.isPrimaryJumping && 
               state.timeUntilCanJump == 0 && 
               state.isStartPrimaryJumping && 
               state.jumpIsLoaded && 
               state.primaryJumpsSinceTouchedGround < moveStats.maxJumps

}
```

While it may add additional lines of code, you know exactly what the condition your checking is.

Answer (score 1):

You should list your conditions with line breaks before '&&':

```
if (state.isPrimaryJumping
    && state.timeUntilCanJump == 0 
    && state.isStartPrimaryJumping 
    && state.jumpIsLoaded 
    && state.primaryJumpsSinceTouchedGround < moveStats.maxJumps) {
      // do awesome jumping stuff
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but isn't that considered a "bad" line break with the `&&` at the beginning

Comment: Nope, I actually thought the same thing though, but I have started reading books and scanning working code examples

Comment: At least, it is completely valid in php, and from my experience has worked in JavaScript, however, php is always ran in the same environment while JavaScript is subject to interpretation from the browser.